# (Program Exited with code :139)

Tags: pi-3, c++

Folks,
I do have an error similar to the main question .

```
Segmentation Error (Program Exited with code :139)
```

I am new to Raspi but have been programming with C & C++ for more than 15 years. My return functions are type-matched with the function assignments and Void when necessary. Actually, `bcm2835_spi_end()` is Void!

I am wondering why the documentation would mention

> bcm2835_spi_end() Returns 1 if successful, 0 otherwise"

which is not a True statement.

Could you please give me a clue why I am getting this error ?

Comment: I think you need to share your code - or even better a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) (see also [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) to get a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Code::Blocks on the Raspberry Pi 4 using exactly the same library (Operating System: Raspberry OS).

I solved this issue by executing Code::Blocks as administrator in the terminal with the command "sudo codeblocks". That means in my case Code::Blocks did not have the necessary rights to get access to specific commands in this library.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.

In my case, was that I was trying to read a text file (.ini) that didn't exist. Check existance first and solved.

Good luck!